# Is Matrix Factorization also going to work with one feature?

Tags: machine-learning, data-imputation, recommender-system, artificial-intelligence

I need to fill missing values. I have found that there are many approaches such as the mean and the median of the feature as well as using Matrix Factorization. However, I am kind of wondering if I can use Matrix Factorization with one feature that is sparse. Hope to hear some about this.

Comment: But why would you like to use it if only one variable is missing?

Answer (score 1):

In matrix factorisation techniques, we try to approximate the $n\times m$ data matrix as a multiplication of $n\times k$ and $k\times m$ matrices. Typically, the number of parameters is reduced, i.e. $nm<k(n+m)$ which indicates that there are patterns in the matrix that can be learnt with lower rank approximations.

In one feature case, i.e. $m=1$:

- you won't be benefitting from low-rank approximations
- you may easily end up with trivial factorisations, or can easily overfit
- I doubt that the dimension $k$ will be interpretable